# How to create a circular diagram with Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I need help to create a circular diagram in Illustrator like this.

I need precisely to represent a percentage. How to do that ?

Thank you.

[image: A circular diagram like this]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in Illustrator CC-2014:

Create the circle:

[image]

Apply the stroke with the desired fill color:

[image]

Place guides in the center:

[image]

Copy circle and apply it to a new layer with `Edit -> Paste in Place`.
Lock `Layer 1` and select `Layer 2`:

[image]

Grab the `Line Segment Tool` and hold down the <kbd>shift</kbd> and drag the length in the center:

[image]

Use the `Align panel` and select the dragged line and circle:

[image]

Copy and paste in place a new line segment than rotate it with the rotate tool and it will tell you the percentage of rotation:

[image]

Select just the line segments and go to `pathfinder` and click <kbd>outline</kbd> then delete the bottom two anchor points with the `direct selection tool`:

[image]

Select everything on `Layer 2` and click the <kbd>outline</kbd> again and delete all unneeded anchors with the `Direct Selection Tool`:

[image]

You should be left with 15% of the circle.

Comment: That answers exactly to my question